# How to use JAXB Java Type Adapters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am having trouble figuring out how @XmlJavaTypeAdapter works with @XmlSeeAlso. I have an abstract class and I specify see also in that class for a class that extends it:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Position.class})
public abstract class Component implements Serializable {
    ...
```

And since Position is does not have a no arg constructor I use Adapters to make it work:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PositionAdapter.class)
public class Position extends Component{ 
    ...
```

However, JAXB seems to ignore this and I still get the "...does not have a no-arg default constructor" error.

Here are my adapters:

```
public class AdaptedPosition {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    @XmlElement(name = "x")
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="y")
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(double x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y){
        this.y = y;
    }
}


public class PositionAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedPosition, Position>{

    @Override
    public AdaptedPosition marshal(Position position) throws Exception {
        AdaptedPosition adaptedPosition = new AdaptedPosition();
        adaptedPosition.setX(position.getX());
        adaptedPosition.setY(position.getY());
        return adaptedPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public Position unmarshal(AdaptedPosition position) throws Exception {
        return new Position(position.getX(), position.getY());
    }

}
```

Does anyone know the reason behind this and what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which code do you run to see that error ? Cannot reproduce it.

```
    Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeElement.class).createMarshaller();
    SomeElement element = new SomeElement();
    element.setPosition(new Position(1, 1));
    marshaller.marshal(element, System.out);
```

This ouputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><someElement><position><x>1.0</x><y>1.0</y></position></someElement>
```